# Квартал года ()

Tags: javascript

Дан месяц как целое число от 1 до 12, вернитесь к тому, к какому кварталу года он принадлежит, как целое число.

Например: 2-й месяц (февраль) является частью первого квартала; 6 месяц (июнь) входит во второй квартал; и месяц 11 (ноябрь) является частью четвертого квартала.

Предлагаю пару решений для новичков(нУбов таких же как я;)

```
const quarterOf = (month) => {  
  if (month <= 3) {  
    return 1  
  } else if (month <= 6) {  
    return 2  
  } else if (month <= 9) {  
    return 3  
  } else if (month <= 12) {  
    return 4  
  }
}
```

или через Метод Math.ceil() - округление вверх. Округляет аргумент до ближайшего большего целого.

```
const quarterOf = m => Math.ceil(m/3);
```

Comment: Вопрос обычно подразумевает вопрос. Хотите задать вопрос и на него сами же ответить, то переделайте вопрос в вопрос, потом оставьте ответ с решением

Comment: принял спасибо ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик, а пустые скобки нафига?

Comment: @Qwertiy  слишком короткий заголовок.

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то последнее условие уже лишнее. Лучше так: `else {  return 4  }`